# ngOninit of child component executing before completing service in parent component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have two component panelComponent(parent) and dashboardComponent(child).
The panelComponent has a subscription to a service in its ngOninit and its return value is used inside childcomponent ngOninit.

The Problem is, on initial running my childs ngOninit executing before Parents service returns a value and I am getting a null result in child component.
How to solve this issue?

panelComponent.ts:-

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.panelService.getUserProfile().subscribe(
        res => {
            this.panelService.userDetails = res;
            this.router.navigate(['panel/dashboard'])
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
        },
    ); 

}
```

panelService.ts:-

```
export class PanelService {
userDetails;
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}
getUserProfile() {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
        })
    };
    return this.http.get('/api/UserProfile/UserProfile', httpOptions);
}
```

dashboardComponent.ts:-

```
    ngOnInit() {

    console.log(this.panelService.userDetails)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> on initial running my childs ngOninit executing before Parents service returns a value

This is because of Async calls. for more about this check here once [Properly use Async calls with Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48098288/properly-use-async-calls-with-angular-5/48098667).

In your case it should work fine, it's better to check the response your getting from the service before redirecting it to the child component.

> **panelComponent.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.panelService.getUserProfile().subscribe(
        res => {
          if(res) {
             this.panelService.userDetails = res;
             this.router.navigate(['panel/dashboard'])
          }
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
     }); 
}
```

I hope this helps..  :)

Answer (score 2):

The most simple way is using a *ngIf. see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxtxwc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) becaouse ngOnInit happens when is in the application the component

I create a dummy service:

```
export class DataService {
  data:any;
  getData()
  {
    return of("Angular").pipe(
      delay(500),
      tap(res=>this.data=res)
    )
  }
}
```

I use pipe(tap) to give value to the propertie "data" of the service, So I needn't do anything also subscribe in any component

In app.component, I has:

```
ngOnInit()
  {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(()=>{});
  }
```

and

```
<hello name="{{ name1 }}"></hello>
<hello *ngIf="dataService.data" name="{{ name2 }}"></hello>
```

In console you see:

```
name1 undefined
name2 Angular
```